# Does SFSpeechRecognizer require internet connection?

Tags: ios, speech-recognition, ios10

Does `SFSpeechRecognizer` work like Siri where the processing is done on Apple servers or is this done locally on the iPhone?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/256/ ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20190616031354/https://theconversation.com/assets/logo-192x192-0dc138eb03a755cacf6c3df151929282.png)), the speech recognition done by SFSpeechRecognizer can be performed on-device (i.e., without connection to a server) for speech recognition:

[image]

[image]

However, [SFSpeechRecognizer's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/speech) ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20190615210258/https://developer.apple.com/documentation/speech)) says:

> **On-device speech recognition is available for some languages, but the framework also relies on Apple’s servers for speech recognition**. Always assume that performing speech recognition requires a network connection.

The documentation and the WWDC 2019 slides above seem to contradict each other.

Answer (score 6):

The description of the speech recognition API at this  [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/content/releasenotes/General/WhatsNewIniOS/Articles/iOS10.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40017084-DontLinkElementID_3) states that

> " In the case of speech recognition, permission is required because
> data is transmitted and temporarily stored on Apple’s servers to
> increase the accuracy of speech recognition."

So that would seem to indicate that processing is taking place on Apple servers.